Does the Dependency Inversion Principle apply within application layers
I keep reading code examples that suggest that the Dependency Inversion Principle is achieved by using interfaces for a classes dependencies. That in itself is confusing me, as the more I read about DIP, the more it appears to be an architectural solution - applied in specific areas (at layer boundaries) within an application - rather than a pattern that should be applied to all classes everywhere, all the time.
Taking the concept of abstraction layers (DDD, Hexagonal or whatever), using an application layer and a transportation layer, it makes sense that we use an interface at this boundary, since then the transportation method (HTTP, Kafka, DB) can change, without impacting the layer which consumes it.
But I am more confused if DIP applies to relationships between classes within the same layer. For example, we have a complex class / logic in the domain layer. We split it up to keep it maintainable and follow Single Responsibility Principle, but it is still complex. It has dependencies from both the application layer and domain layer. For its application layer dependencies, we use interfaces since those dependencies cross the application / domain layer boundary (and the application layer could change over time), but what about the dependencies within the domain layer?
To expand further, the dependencies within the domain layer are logic that I instinctively know will not change in the applications lifecycle. The dependencies are, from a logic point of view, tightly coupled to each other. (The same argument could also apply to complex logic / classes in any other layer)
If we take a traditional interface (in languages which support it) at face-value, it defines a contract to be implemented. This is beneficial at boundary layers for exactly the reason that the layer can change without impacting whatever is consuming the interface. But in the example where we know the logic will not change, within the same layer, is there any benefit to using an interface? - And is that even DIP?
In a previous (poorly worded question), and from reading online, one benefit I had read to using interfaces for - all - dependencies - everywhere -, was that it made testing easier in some frameworks, but it appears that is simply not true.
So to highlight my two main points of confusion; Does DIP apply to

Dependencies between classes within the same layer
Dependencies which will not change their implementation or have multiple implementations


If you don't care about keeping couplings loose, indeed, there is no reason to add this complexity, whose purpose is to ensure couplings are loose.

On a possible source of confusion

I keep reading code examples that suggest that the Dependency Inversion Principle is achieved by using interfaces for a classes dependencies.

That's unfortunate, and I can see how this is confusing, but the more nebulous a term, the more vulnerable it is to semantic diffusion. As non-mathematical notions go, the Dependency Inversion Principle (DIP) isn't even that vague, so the core idea remains relatively intact a few decades after the idea was first presented.
Even so, the more people rehash an idea and put their own spin on it, the more diluted it becomes, and the more mistakes creep in.
One thing that bothers me about the software industry broadly speaking is the general lack of academic rigour. If authors of blog posts etc. even cite any sources at all, it's often some other derived piece of work.
All this to say that you may find it illuminating to go back to the original source. The five SOLID principles originate from Bertrand Meyer, Barbara Liskov, and Robert C. Martin, but were popularized as a 'package' by Martin (with the help of Michael Feathers, who suggested the acronym).
When things are confusing, it sometimes help cutting through all the intermediate layers of interpretation and instead consulting the source. As a start, I'll recommend going back to Robert C. Martin's work, which is still quite readable. You may be able to find scattered PDFs from the nineties, when he first started to explore the principles, but otherwise, one of the APPP books should help (I usually refer to the C# version, but there's an earlier edition with examples in Java, I believe).
I'm sorry about this long-winded preamble, but I understand the confusion. If you're consulting 'random' articles on the internet, that can happen.
And to be blunt, although I did link to Wikipedia, I consider its articles on SOLID etc. to be of varying quality. And you never know what claims a given Wikipedia article will make tomorrow.
If all of this establishes that there's a lot of random people on the internet who write down their idiosyncratic interpretations of things, what makes me different? Why should you listen to me?
I'm not that different, and you should only listen to me if you can make sense of what I write. Perhaps I've already lost you.
I do, however, attempt to cite original sources when possible. (I also link a lot to my own blog, which isn't an attempt at sleight of hand, but mostly to link to a more expanded argument than what fits here on Stack Overflow.)
Architecture

the more I read about DIP, the more it appears to be an architectural solution

That's also how I interpret Robert C. Martin's writings on the topic.

It has dependencies from both the application layer and domain layer

We have to be careful here. As I read the OP, from the context I take it that you understand the concept correctly. Even so, precision in language may at times prevent confusion.
You're here talking about run-time dependencies; i.e. when running, an object depends on another object that I may invoke in order to get work done.
This isn't the same as a compile-time dependency (in compiled languages), where, in order to compile a piece of code, another library or module also has to be available.
A major reason why the DIP uses the term inversion is because it inverts the direction of dependencies so that run-time dependencies and compile-time dependencies point in different directions. At run time the dependency points one way, but at compile time it points the opposite way.
Inter-layer dependencies
Does the DIP apply within a given layer?
I usually don't interpret it that way, but I suppose that it ultimately depends on how big and complex a given 'layer' is.
Notice that the DIP doesn't mention interfaces, but rather talks in terms of abstraction:

"A. High-level modules should not depend on low-level modules. Both should depend on abstractions.
"B. Abstractions should not depend upon details. Details should depend upon abstractions."
- APPP, Robert C. Martin, Prentice Hall, 2006

In APPP Robert C. Martin only obliquely refers to a definition of 'abstraction', but as far as I've been able to track down, we can find it in one of his earlier works:

Abstraction is the elimination of the irrelevant and the amplification of the essential.
- Designing Object-Oriented C++ Applications Using The Booch Method, Robert C. Martin, Prentice Hall, 1995, chapter 00, his emphasis

My point is that the DIP does not constrain itself to discuss interfaces or other kinds of polymorphism. Rather, it works on the level of a 'hierarchy of abstraction'.
You could, conceivably, have such a hierarchy even within a module, but I don't think that it's the most common scenario.
Relatedly, however, I strongly recommend that you explicitly consider dependencies even within modules. Scott Wlaschin has a fascinating analysis of dependency cycles in real-world code, on which Dr. Evalina Gabasova later expanded. The more cyclic dependencies you have, the closer you get to spaghetti code.

Thank you kindly, this is a great answer which address all of my concerns, with a lot of valuable information to digest in the linked articles. The preamble is appreciated too, even if just to glimpse the history of why the SOLID principles came into being

Are you aware of any DIP-compliant example from Robert Martin that does not utilize polymorphism? The original paper along with some of Martin's lectures certainly seem to imply the DIP requires polymorphism.

Furthermore, the only reason abstract interfaces are not explicitly required seems to be that Martin likes to point out how polymorphism in languages like C is achieved through function pointers instead. The SOLID principles are squarely targeted at OO languages, so it seems like polymorphic interfaces are required by the DIP, at least within its targeted paradigm.

I don't think we should draw a conclusion about the DIP's reliance on polymorphism or interfaces solely from a two-sentence summary; however, choosing two different sentences from the A and B above, "The structure that results from rigorous use of [the OCP and the LSP] can be generalized into a principle all by itself. I call it 'The Dependency Inversion Principle' (DIP)." If we say the DIP does not require interfaces or polymorphism, then neither must its constituent principles: the OCP and the LSP, right?

@jaco0646 No, I'm not aware of any of Martin's examples that don't use polymorphism, but I asked him: https://x.com/unclebobmartin/status/1817263979774816379

Bertrand Meyer formulated the most important principle of object-oriented design - The Open Closed Principle (OCP):

A module should be open for extension but closed for modification.

The Open Closed Principle defines the purpose of object-oriented design (What) — We want to be able to change the behavior of modules without changing the source code of the modules.

One of the formulations of The Dependency Inversion Principle (DIP) by Robert Martin (it seems to me the most clear):

Depend upon Abstractions. Do not depend upon concretions.

If The Open Closed Principle determines the goal (What), then The Dependency Inversion Principle determines the mechanism (How) — dependency should target an interface, or an abstract class (should not target a concrete class).

The main reasons for using The Dependency Inversion Principle include:

The concreate changes more often than the abstract (changing the interface changes the implementation, changing the concrete class does not always change the implementation). Thus, by applying The Dependency Inversion Principle you get rid of the need to depend on volatile modules.
Dependencies on abstractions represent points where functionality can be extended without changing their source code.


By applying The Dependency Inversion Principle you get the benefits described above regardless of the place of application (layer).
